# How can I tell if Gensim Word2Vec is using the C compiler?

Tags: python, compilation, installation, gensim, word2vec

I am trying to use Gensim's Word2Vec implementation. Gensim warns that if you don't have a C compiler, the training will be 70% slower.  Is there away to verify that Gensim is correctly using the C Compiler I have installed?

I am using Anaconda Python 3.5 on Windows 10.

Comment: It helps a lot if you tell us what platform you're using, and what installer you used?

Comment: Added info on the platform and installer, however I think I found the answer and it is platform and install independent (see my answer below).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Apparently gensim offers a variable to detect this:

```
assert gensim.models.doc2vec.FAST_VERSION > -1
```

I found this line in this tutorial:
https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/docs/notebooks/doc2vec-IMDB.ipynb

Answer (score 2):

Gensim provides both wheels and an installer for Windows.

```
pip install gensim
```

should get you gensim with Cython optimization without the work of getting Cython up and running (not that it's not great to have Cython, but sometimes it's nice to just have stuff run).